# Unable to create png using renjin

Tags: r, renjin

Hey I am trying create png file using **renjin** ,but it's giving me following error
**Object 'Cdevga' not found.**

**More details ::**

renjin version  > 0.8.2294

script  > png('test.png')

I also tried to use **png('test.png',type = 'cairo')** .. It gives error Object devCairo not found

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Renjin does not currently provide an implementation the graphics or grDevices packages.